# WooCommerce - Access 'WC_Order' from a separate PHP File

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Javascript to call a PHP file directly from my functions.php file in WooCommerce (via Wordpress) which is using the 'PHP XLSXWriter' code available on GitHub. However, I'm having trouble accessing

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
```

Can I access this function directly behind WooCommerce by perhaps using

```
 require_once('/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php');
```

?

Here is my entire PHP code which I'm calling:

```
$order_id = $_GET['order']; // pull the order info from the URL 
$order = new WC_Order($order_id); // this crashes this entire function!
echo $order->shipping_city; // this then fails
echo $order->shipping_country; // and this fails too

// this code doesn't then execute...
$filename = "test.xlsx";
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.XLSXWriter::sanitize_filename($filename).'"');
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

$rows = array(
    array('Shipping Service Code',  'Company',  'Consignee Name',   'Address Line 1',   'Address Line 2',   'Address Line 3'),
    array('PPS',                    '-',        '-',                '-',                '-',                '-'),
);

$writer = new XLSXWriter();
$writer->setAuthor('EXAMPLE AUTHOR');

foreach($rows as $row)
$writer->writeSheetRow('Sheet1', $row);
$writer->writeToStdOut();

exit(0);
```

The error I get is:

```
 Fatal error: Class 'WC_Order' not found in C:\Webs\mysite.com\www\wp-admin\dhlgen.php on line 9
```

Another idea is if it's possible to just call the PHP code directly in my function.php file. However, I have it on a meta_box button, so when I click on the button itself, it just saves the order and doesn't execute my PHP code. Reason I think that might be is because the XLSXWriter logic needs to stop the page in order the dump the Excel spreadsheet file which it can't do, so it times out and continues just saving the page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to access the WordPress environment (including WooCommerce) by including the `wp-blog-header` file:

```
require('path/to/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Or, alternatively the `wp-load` file:

```
require('path/to/wp-load.php');
```

---

[**Intergration Docs**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) | [**Related Question**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47059/48436)

Comment: Okay, now I am getting a new error. "Catchable fatal error: Object of class WC_Order could not be converted to string". This line: echo $order;

Comment: That's because `$order` is an object, not a string. If you want to see what `$order` contains, use `var_dump($order)`

Comment: Perfect! Working nicely now. Thank you so much for that. This file will be readable though by the public, won't it? Is there any way to fix that??

Comment: Sure, no problem!  Yes, it would be accessible to anyone who knows it is there.  You can use `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: your-domain.com');` to help control access to that file.

Comment: Okay, and lastly, how would I add the object data to my array? EG: `array('PPS',     '-',  $order->shipping_first_name,    '-',    '-',    '-'),` (line 16 in my example).

Comment: That should work, eg: `array('PPS', '-', $order->shipping_first_name, ...`

Comment: Ah yes, that is working indeed. The problem was the XLSX paser routines didn't like how I had echo's still in there because when I was trying to open the file, it was corrupted. Thanks again for all your help. Legendary.

Comment: Excellent! No worries :)

Comment: This helped me a lot :D, Thanks